# Instantiate and Fire Object, when OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I would like a bullet that is fired from the Enemy, to bounce back off my Players shield.

I have set up my character and the enemy fires towards me at time intervals.
I can then activate my players shield (turning on a BoxCollider) and pressing a button.

So when the Bullet (IsTrigger) collides with my Players Shield (IsNotTrigger) I want to remove this Bullet and then Instantiate a new Bullet from the shield, in the direction of the Enemy.
I am also having an issue destroying the Bullet.

When the OnTriggerEvent or OnColliderEvent occurs (tried both), hundreds of bullets will appear from my Shield.  How do I only allow one bullet to be fired towards the enemy?

Below is part of my script, which is located in the GameObject of my Players Shield.
Ideally I would like to destroy the bullet once it has collided with an object.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    if (col.tag == "Weapon") {

        attack();
    }
}

private void attack() {

    if (!GameManager.instance.GameOver) {

    bulletReturnClone = Instantiate(bulletReturn, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    bulletReturnClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * 25f;
```

Comment: Do Your bulletReturn prefab has a "Weapon" tag?

Comment: Yeah it has a "Weapon" tag

Comment: Your new bullet propably triggers instatiating new ones, so a lot of bullets apear.

Comment: Yeah that sort of makes sense.  Perhaps my bullet is Instantiated inside my box collider.  So my fireLoctation needs to be outside this box collider.

Comment: Lat us know if it solve Your problem.

Comment: Alternatively you could use different tags. E.g. "enemyWeapon" and "playerWeapon" to differentiate who owns what so that when the collision / trigger event happens you can discriminate.

Comment: HI there,
Managed to solve my issue.  I basically reflect the bullet off the BoxCollider now.  This is alot easier than Instantiating a new Bullet every time.  Thanks for your help. 
I reckon my bullet was being triggered early on and instantiating lots of them.  The enemyWeapon and PlayerWeapon was a good idea.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strachan,

That's not how I would approach the problem but I will stick to your desired solution then share some ideas for improvement.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
if (col.tag == "Weapon") {

    attack(col);
    }
}

private void attack(Collider col) {

if (!GameManager.instance.GameOver) {

bulletReturnClone = Instantiate(bulletReturn,  transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
bulletReturnClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * 25f;
// the following line of code should remove the bullet from the shield collider in order to prevent any future problems like spawning multiple bullets or instantly destroying the newly created bullet
bulletReturnClone.GetComponent<Transform>().position *= bulletReturnClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity; 
Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

If your trigger(Bullet) is tagged as weapon this code should achieve your intentional goal of reflecting the bullet in the direction of your shield pointing to by destroying the bullet and instantiating a new one and modifying it's velocity. It works but it's kind of sloppy development. It can be much better if you approach the problem from a different perspective - the one of the Bullet not the Shield.

Let's pretend for a moment you are a Bullet. All you do is fly in the direction you are shot. Once you collide with a terrain you stop/disappear. If this terrain is a shield you don't stop/disappear but change your direction (you get reflected).
  So... long story short... the one who should have a trigger collider is the bullet not the shield. OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) for the bullet script will destroy it but if col.tag == "Shield" the bullet will only change its direction without all the useless instantiations and transformations.
I'm too lazy to write the code  for the 2nd solution. If you got my point you should be able to easily write it down. Also learning through trials and errors helps you develop (excuse for me being lazy).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, this makes alot of sense.
Its alot easier to reflect the Object instead of instantiating a new one.
I've accepted your answer based on your last paragraph.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Im not really sure why you would want to despawn and respawn the bullet with a new velocity?

Depending on the shield geometry you could look up Coefficients of Restitution and therefore reflect the kinetic energy of the bullet into a realistic velocity.

Note the complexity of that maths will be proportional to the complexity of your shield geometry depending on the different collision primitives.

- Sphere-sphere
- Sphere-plane
- Sphere-terrain (terrain could represent any un-even surface)

Or are you trying to collect the bullets in some sort of "charge" mechanic to release them back at a different time?

Comment: Hi thanatorr, thanks for your reply.
I was initially thinking of reflecting the bullet however, I thought Destroying and instantiating a new Bullet would be easier.  

Imagine if the Enemy is directly in front of my Player and shoots a bullet.  I want to use my shield (box Collider) to reflect the bullet back towards the Enemy.

So as the bullet (OnTriggerEvent) collides with the Shield.  Then I could Destroy the bullet and then Instantiate a new bullet from the shield location and send this back towards the Enemy position.

Comment: ok well in terms of good practise, especially for game programmers you may be using up a few too many processing cycles doing something like that. But if we want to just "make it work" maybe implementing a list of bullets on the shield and just expelling a bullet on `event_tick()` `if (list.Count > 0)`. Unfortunately i don't know the exact syntax as im much ore experiences with Unreal Engine. But if your still struggling i will try to check it out.

Comment: Thanks thanatorr for your help.
I decided to reflect the object off the BoxCollider.  This is alot easier than Instantiating the object repeatedly.
Thanks again.